# jQuery get IFRAME content and set that to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a file called iframe.html, which contains the code to for a image slideshow or etc. The code is somewhat like

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>

  <body>
    <iframe id="i1" src="test.html"></iframe>
    <div id='i2'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

i want to get content of iframe and set `i2` with that in jQuery such as:

```
    $(document).ready(){
        var i1= $('#i1').contents();
        $('#i2').html( i1 );
    }
```

that do not correct, how to resolve that?

Comment: Unless you need the `iframe` for some other reason, you may only need to use the jQuery `load` function to grab the content from your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change : `<iframe id="i1" src="test.html"></iframe>`

to

`<iframe id="i1" src="test.html" onload='aaa();'></iframe>`

And add :

```
function aaa(){

 var a=  $('#i1').contents().find("html").html()
 $('#i2').html( a );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the console, you'll probably see a syntax error.

Add the closing parenthese after your `$(document).ready` and the `function` keyword, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { // function here
    var i1= $('#i1').contents();
    $('#i2').html( i1 );
}); // closing parenthese here
```